# Excel VBA Loop column and copy data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need some help with a bit of code i'm trying to write. I am not very experienced in VBA, I thought a VLookup is what i needed but after thinking about it. I think a Find loop with work even better.

There will be a button click on sheet1.

The code will need to do the following, in sheet "Global" use column B and search range, each row will have a different value, it will need to search the cell value row by row, in Sheet "Details"  if match found then copy the data from columns H, F & E and paste into columns O, P & Q in the Global sheet. H = O, E = P, D = Q. Loop through until first empty row.

In the Details sheet, in column B if there was no data matching from Details then the row will get deleted.

**For Example:**

Global Before:
[image]

Details Before:
[image]

**After Code has run:**

Global After:
[image]

Details After:
[image]

Hopefully this explains it well enough, as you can seen it has found the matching data and copied it to the relevant rows, all non matching data has been deleted.

I have no code at the moment because if i honest i have no idea where to start!!! All help is much appreciated!!

Comment: From reading it, I would have thought Vlookup should do what you need. What made you think otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. note that you will need to have an empty column that will temporarly hold a mark if the value in the row has been found — in my example i used the "I" column, you will need to modify this if it's not empty.

```
Private Sub pasteValues()
Dim i, j, lastG, lastD As Long

' find last row
lastG = Sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
lastD = Sheets("Details").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' loop over values in "Global"
For i = 1 To lastG
    lookupVal = Sheets("Global").Cells(i, "B") ' value to find

    ' loop over values in "details"
    For j = 1 To lastD
        currVal = Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "B")

        If lookupVal = currVal Then
            Sheets("Global").Cells(i, "O") = Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "H")
            Sheets("Global").Cells(i, "P") = Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "E")
            Sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q") = Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "D")
            ' mark the row
            Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "I") = "marked"

        End If
    Next j
Next i

' loop over rows in "details" and delete rows which have not been marked
For j = 1 To lastD
    If Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "I") <> "marked" Then
        ' delete unmarked rows
        Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        If Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "B") <> "" Then
            j = j - 1 ' revert iterator so it doesn't skip rows
        End If
    Else:
        ' remove the mark
        Sheets("Details").Cells(j, "I") = ""
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```